# how to set the Keep_Fragments parameter to True?

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a site that utilizes Js, but scrapy keeps dropping the next page url as  duplicate and stoping the crawl. From my reading, it's my understanding that scrapy checks for duplicates by checking the hash of the resource the request points to and by defualt will drop the fragments in the URL. This behaviour can be changed by altering the Keep_Fragments command in the request_fingerprint module. (see the excerpt from scrapy release notes bellow)

"A new keep_fragments parameter of scrapy.utils.request.request_fingerprint() allows to generate different fingerprints for requests with different fragments in their URL (issue 4104)"

My question is, how does one actually modify this parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the request fingerprinting logic of the duplicate request filter is possible by writing your custom duplicate request filter. It will also [get easier](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/4524) in a future version of Scrapy.

However, after you do that you will find out that Scrapy does not evaluate JavaScript code on its own. In the end, it is probably not in your best interest to change the duplicate request detection logic.

The [Scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html) covers how to extract that type of information with Scrapy.